# Extend Plugin Class In Child Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, woocommerce

I am using PHP code like this in my child theme to override a WooCommerce plugin public function where Item is the plugin parent class.

```
class New_Item extends Item {

 
    public function modified_function() {



    }
    
}

$new = New_Item;

$new->modified_function();
```

The error i get is :

```
Uncaught Error: Class "Item" not found in wp-content/themes/2020-child/woocommerce/New_Item.php:20
```

Line 20 is this :

```
class New_Item extends Item {
```

I am loading the file for the extended class using this in child themes functions :

```
require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/New_Item.php';
```